# How to schedule a java console program in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, cron, putty

I've been reading about it, and I've tried one of the solutions that I've found in the internet, but it still doesn't work yet.
I want to execute

`java -jar /home/ubuntu/MyJavaJar.jar`

once a year starting in October 12 at 12:34

I'm sorry if this is a really basic question, but I can't find a solution yet. I don't have a graphic interface, so the solution should be using the console.

Also, if there was another way to do this (without using linux cron) e.g. connect using putty and launch the java jar and then disconnect from putty (in my windows-based computer, that needs to be turned off regularly) (but without cancelling the jar execution on the Linux computer, that doesn't need to be turned off) would be an even better answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you not use cron for task like this? Running something periodically is the exact thing cron was meant to be doing.

Comment: My jar uses an internal cron (by cron4j) so executing it once and letting it running without interruption during an amount of time (one year) would provide me the data that I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nohup:

```
nohup java -jar /home/ubuntu/MyJavaJar.jar &
```